# Pass key of object via arguments

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
function cmp_asc($a, $b){
    $ta = date_create_from_format('Y/m/d', $a['props']['t']); //  Y/n/j  si no tienen 0 inicial
    $tb = date_create_from_format('Y/m/d', $b['props']['t']);
    $interval = date_diff($ta, $tb);

    if($interval->days != 0){
        if($interval->invert == 1){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

$arr1 = array(
    'props' => array('t' => '2012/05/20')
);

$arr2 = array(
    'props' => array('t' => '2012/05/21')
);

$arr3 = array(
    'props' => array('t' => '2012/04/14')
);

$arr = array($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);

uasort($arr, 'cmp_asc');
```

and I'd like to know if I can pass the `['props']['t']` via arguments. 
So, it will end up like:

```
function cmp_asc($a, $b, $key){
    $ta = date_create_from_format('Y/m/d', $a <-- $key -->);
    ...
...
```

I'm thinking about variable variables, but I'm not too sure this is the right way to do it. 
Any other ideas?

Comment: This is a classic problem that crops up here a lot. What you are essentially asking is "how can I dynamically retrieve a value from an array key at an arbitrary depth in a multidimensional array, without passing the value itself" - and the short answer is you can't do it cleanly. There are some nasty reference-driven looping techniques that can be applied but they (slightly counter-intuitively) won't work if the thing you want to get is itself a reference. People often resort to `eval()` driven methods, but these are equally horrible. I'll try and find some related question links.

Comment: Where is the array coming from, I wonder if there is a chance of sorting it before it gets here?

Comment: The array gets from a JSON string. So, it can't be sorted in any other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really as argument, because you're not calling the function yourself, but you can use [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to pass other variables into the function:

```
$key1 = 'props';
$key2 = 't';

uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($key1, $key2) {
    $ta = date_create_from_format('Y/m/d', $a[$key1][$key2]);
    ...
});
```

That's just a simple example. If you need dynamic key depths, this'll need a bit more code, along these lines:

```
function getValue(array $value, $key) {
    $keys = explode('.', $key);
    foreach ($keys as $k) {
        $value = $value[$k];
    }
    return $value;
}

$arr = array('foo' => array('bar' => 'baz'));
echo getValue($arr, 'foo.bar');
```

Another idea would be using a class, usage of which would look like this:

```
$cmp = new ComparisonClass;
$cmp->key = 'props.t';

uasort($arr, array($cmp, 'compare'));
```

I'll let you figure out the implementation of `ComparisonClass`.

A nicer solution may be to simply standardize the format of the array you're going to sort.

Comment: I like the first solution, the problem is that I'll probably need dynamic key depth.

Comment: Then there are numerous question here about how to, for example, resolve `'props.t'` to `$arr['props']['t']`. Try it yourself or do a search.

Comment: Well, the array will always have 1, 2 or 3 levels as it's comming from a JSON string. (if that makes any difference)

Comment: @alexandernst If the depth is finite and known you could just use the first method suggested here and use an `if`/`elseif` tree in the function. Just do `if (isset($key1, $key2, $key2)) { /* 3 levels */ } elseif (isset($key1, $key2)) { /* 2 levels */ } ...`

Comment: @deceze props.t doesn't resolve to [props][t] in this case. I'm wondering why?